# Display 'Change Item Order' in REST API call in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I'm display the contents of a Links List (named QuickLinks) on a page. I want to display the links in the order defined by the 'Change Item Order' feature of the Links List. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's what I have for making the call to get the data:

```
//AJAX call utilizing REST API to get list items
getQuickLinks: function (success) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/QuickLinks?$orderby=DisplayOrder",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data){
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

};

Comment: Do you actually have a field called DisplayOrder in your list?

Comment: No I don't. I created a links list. The 'Change Item Order' can be access from the ribbon. See here http://puu.sh/hEc2C/2a41b89261.png

Comment: You'll need to use the [/views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_View) tag for your API call and specify a view you've created that is associate with that list or you'll need to use the [$orderby](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sectionSection5) option if you just want to define it in the script itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are referring to built-in `Order` column of OOTB `Links` list that is used for storing selected item order.

If so, unfortunately you have to consider another options (`CSOM` or `SharePoint Web Services`) since in SharePoint 2010 it does not seem possible to accomplish via REST interlace:

> `Order` column of `Links` list is not accessible via SharePoint 2010
>   REST interface

The example below demonstrates how to return Link list items sorted by `Order` column using CSOM:

```
function getListItems(listTitle,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var items = list.getItems(createLinksByOrderQuery());
   ctx.load(items);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       success(items);
   },error);
}


function createLinksByOrderQuery()
{
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    qry.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll">' + 
      '<Query>' + 
         '<OrderBy>' + 
           '<FieldRef Name="Order" Ascending="FALSE"/>' +
         '</OrderBy>' + 
      '</Query>' + 
    '</View>');
    return qry; 
}


getListItems('Links',
      function(items)
      {
           items.get_data().forEach(function(item){
              console.log(item.get_item('Order')); 
           });

      },
      function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
     });
```

**About SharePoint 2013**

In SharePoint 2013 you could sort items by `Order` column as demonstrated below:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Links')/items?$orderby=Order asc
```

Example:

```
var getLinkItems = function (webUrl, listTitle) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle +  "')/items?$orderby=Order asc",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}



getLinkItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Links')
   .done(function(data){
      data.d.results.forEach(function(item){
         console.log(item.URL); 
      });  
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```

Comment: Just saved me a couple of hours right there. Tx Vadmin